# What is "cracked up to be"?

Tags: slang

> The financial burden of government lockdowns made one thing clear, that urban life isn't all that it's cracked up to be.

What is the meaning of "cracked up to be" here?

[Source](https://youtu.be/R6HQm3ZzyhM?t=712)

Comment: It's an idiom. You can look it up.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as "it's not all that it's made out to be". These phrases refer to something that is generally thought of as being good but after some revelation, it is clear that it is not as good as it was thought.